# How to prevent Linux from absorbing Windows boot manager?

Tags: grub, boot-loader

I have 2 SSDs plugged in my server. One installed Windows Server 2019, the other RadHat 8.3.

What is sort of annoying to me is that every time I installed Windows and RedHat, **RedHat will delete the original Windows Boot Manager and Create a new one in its own EFI partition**, no matter the installation orders of them.

Is there a way to

1. undo what RedHat did
2. and prevent that from happening in future?

Answer (score 2):

First, is the RedHat installer really deleting the contents of the Windows' EFI partition (unlikely unless you chose the partition to be reformatted)?

After the installation of RedHat, run `efibootmgr -v` to see the NVRAM boot variables.

The Windows boot entry should look similar to this:

```
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,12345678-9abc-def0-1234-56789abcdef0,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.0.1.2.3.4.5.6.7.-.8.9.a.b.-.c.d.e.f.-.0.1.2.3.-.4.5.6.7.8.9.a.b.c.d.e.f.}...d................
```

If the "Windows Boot Manager" entry is gone, you should be able to reconstruct it with:

```
efibootmgr -c -L "Windows Boot Manager" -l \\EFI\\MICROSOFT\\BOOT\\BOOTMGFW.EFI -d <disk containing Windows ESP>
```

(Sure, it'll be missing the extra binary argument that is used by Windows, but it seems Windows might be able to recover that on its own. The first GUID in the Windows Boot Manager entry should be automatically generated by `efibootmgr` to match the PARTUUID of the ESP partition that contains the Windows Boot Manager.)

If the Windows entry is just deactivated or pushed down in the priority list, you can use other `efibootmgr` options to fix it. I think this is the most likely thing to happen, unless your system firmware has some quirks in how it deals with the UEFI boot variables.

For example, some UEFI implementations will "helpfully" delete any boot entries that seem to refer to disks that are no longer present. If a system disk develops an intermittent failure, such a behavior might add extra steps to the recovery process.